# .NET Application hosted under default website in IIS behaves differently with same application hosted as different site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I have this weired situation and want to understand why this is happening.

I have a .NET MVC 5 Application hosted in iis as:

- Application under default website with a separate app pool.(default
  site has other applications as well)
- Separate Website (different app pool)

But some functionalities not work for the app inside default website, however for Separate website all functionalities work as expected.
The publish package is same for both of them. IIS: 8, Windows Server 2012.

I'm Trying to understand the reason, and is there any way I can fix this for default site?

Edit: Some functionalities include Undo process which involves changing the status in database table and deleting the file which is generated and saved on disk.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: "some functionalities..." - a key thing here is to identify what those functions have in common that is distinct to them as opposed to the other functions which are working. That's work you need to put in that we're unable to. Once you've determined what they have in common, and if it doesn't become obvious what the issue is, please edit that into the question.

Comment: Some functionalities include Undo process which involves changing the status in database table and deleting the file which is generated and saved on disk. I have also make it sure that the APP Pool has rights to delete the file.